# Using a large API via custom connectors. API's definition exceeds the 1MB file size limit

Tags: azure-logic-apps

The company I work for uses a product named Pension Pro for workflow management. They offer an API and we would like to look into using it for automating tasks and connecting multiple systems. We want to do this through Azure Logic Apps and/or Microsoft Flow.

Pension Pro provides documentation for their API on their website here: https://api.pensionpro.com/#/

In theory, I should be able to save down the API documentation from their website and import it into Azure. The issue is, once saved to a text file, the API exceeds the 1MB file limit for importing an OpenAPI file.

I tried copy/pasting the JSON data into the swagger editor inside of Azure and ran into issues when saving the connector as well.

What would a solution to this problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to use the [Azure API Management Built-In Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list#built-ins).

You can [import the OpenAPI spec into APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-api-from-oas) and then use the built-in connector to call the operations directly from Logic Apps.

[image: built-in-apim-connector]